# How to use Java to move Windows windows around on screen?

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface, window-managers, window-management

I've been contemplating making a window manager with a GUI, probably in Java. However, I'm struggling to figure out the best way to move windows not owned by my program.

So far, it would seem I should use JNI to interface with the Windows API, but I haven't found any helpful examples.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

PS. I'm not necessarily tied to Java, if there is a better language to do this in.

Comment: I'm sure any language that is native would be far better than a VM environment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the purpose is to have a fast window manager you are certainly better off with C++ or C#, or maybe even Delphi.

But if you are most familiar with Java it can be done.

If you choose the (aging) JNI you would have to write a DLL in C or Delphi that you Java application will use. You should use [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) instead to access the Windows' window handling API functions.

Some of the functions you would use are:

```
    HWND WINAPI GetWindow(HWND hWnd, UINT uCmd);
    HWND WINAPI FindWindow(LPCTSTR lpClassName, LPCTSTR lpWindowName);
    BOOL WINAPI EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, LPARAM lParam);
    HWND WINAPI WindowFromPoint(POINT Point);
    BOOL WINAPI MoveWindow(HWND hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, BOOL bRepaint);
```

Once you get the window handle (HWND) you can do whatever you like with that window.

[EnumWindows function reference at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)